# Messages stuck or lost in ActiveMQ cluster

Tags: configuration, activemq-classic

I've set up a small ActiveMQ Network of Brokers to increase reliability. It consists of 3 nodes with the following properties (full config template file is [available here](https://gist.github.com/msteiger/7585dfcd5bcf0c77e45c56e0411c45a1)):

- ActiveMQ Version 5.13.3 (latest as of July 16)
- Local LevelDB persistence adapter
- NetworkConnector `uri="static:(tcp://${OTHER_NODE1}:61616,tcp://${OTHER_NODE2}:61616)"` with the two variables set for e.g. `node2` to `node1` and `node3` (uni-directal conn. between all nodes).

Clients connect with `failover:(tcp://node1:61616,tcp://node2:61616,tcp://node3:61616)`, send and retrieve messages as needed.
The `failover` protocol randomizes the target machine, so messages might be sent back and forth inside the cluster.

There are two (failing) scenarios:

- As it is described now, some messages are not delivered, because they are not allowed to go "back". This is done to avoid loops and described in [this blog post](http://tmielke.blogspot.de/2012/03/i-have-messages-on-queue-but-they-dont.html).
- Activating the `replayWhenNoConsumers` flag as described in the blog and in [NoB: Stuck Messages](http://activemq.apache.org/networks-of-brokers.html) causes those messages to be recognized as duplicates.With `enableAudit` enabled, I get `cursor got duplicate send ID`, disabling it gives me a `<MSG> paged in, is cursor audit disabled? Removing from store and redirecting to dlq`.

Maybe this is trivial to fix - anybody has an idea?